# Save ManyToMany records to rails backend

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble persisting associated records to a Rails backend with ember-data.

Models:

```
FP.Student = DS.Model.extend

  firstName:    DS.attr('string')
  lastName:     DS.attr('string')
  imageUrl:     DS.attr('string')

  room:         DS.hasMany('FP.Room')
  parents:      DS.hasMany('FP.Parent')
  observations: DS.hasMany('FP.Observation')


FP.Observation = DS.Model.extend

  name:         DS.attr('string')
  description:  DS.attr('string')
  observedAt:   DS.attr('string')

  room:         DS.belongsTo('FP.Room')
  educator:     DS.belongsTo('FP.Educator')
  students:     DS.hasMany('FP.Student', embedded: true)
```

I want to add a list of pre-existing students from a Select view to a new Observation. Assuming the Student models have be collected in `controller.selectedStudents` I do:

```
 saveObservation: ->
    console.log "ObservationsController saveObservation"
    obs = @get('newObservation') # new observation is created previously
    obs.set('observedAt', new Date)
    obs.set('room', @get('room'))
    obs.set('educator', @get('room.educators').objectAt(0))
    selected = @findSelectedStudents()
    obs.get('students').pushObjects(selected)
    obs.get('transaction').commit()

findSelectedStudents: ->
    @get('selectedStudents').map( (id) =>
      @get('students').find( (student) ->
        student.id is id
      )
    )
```

The resulting json sent back to the server looks like (this is from the server log):

```
Started POST "/observations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-24 21:04:12 +1000
Processing by ObservationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"observation"=>
{"name"=>"DDS", "description"=>"asdsad", "observed_at"=>"Wed Apr 24 2013 21:04:04 GMT+1000 (EST)", "room_id"=>203, "educator_id"=>535, 
"students"=>[{"id"=>605, "first_name"=>"Steven", "last_name"=>"Richards", "image"=>"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CTUCsDGwdEVaS"},
 {"id"=>607, "first_name"=>"Anna", "last_name"=>"Stone", "image"=>"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CTUCsDGwdEVaS"}]}}
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
```

Sorry about the layout, but there are 2 students, with full attribute lists. The error the server throws is `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Student(#70343949384800) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70343953246680)`

Now, I've got this working with an ajax callback that serializes the students to a `student_ids` array, containing just the student ids. The server accepts this call and sets up the association. But I'd prefer to use ember-data and not have the hassle of manual record management I've found with a hand-rolled ajax solution.

I've tried setting an array of `student_ids` on the Observation, but then nothing is sent back to the server.

I think the current call could work if the association was named `student_attributes`, but it seems a waste of time to send all the data if the student record isn't dirty.

So, should I be trying to override the serializer to send back an array of student_ids? Or am I missing something else?

thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist a Many to Many relationship on the server, I'm hacking the `hasMany` method of the serializer to add an option `serialized` in the mapping.

Here is the serializer (CoffeeScript) :

```
App.Serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend

  # redefine to make it possible to serialize a relationship by an array of ids
  # to enable it, a 'serialized' property should be set to 'ids' in the adapter mapping
  # the key in the hash will be the type of the object in the relation ship + _ids'
  # example : for an hasMany('App.Category'), the key will be category_ids
  addHasMany: (hash, record, key, relationship) ->
    type = record.constructor
    name = relationship.key

    serializedType = @serializedType type, name

    if serializedType is 'ids'
      key = @singularize(@keyForAttributeName(type, name)) + "_ids"
      manyArray = record.get name
      serializedIds = []
      manyArray.forEach (record) ->
        serializedIds.push record.get('id')
      hash[key] = serializedIds
    else
      return @_super hash, record, key, relationship

  # method to access the serialized option in adapter mapping
  serializedType: (type, name) ->
    @mappingOption type, name, 'serialized'
```

And here is a mapping configuration exemple :

```
App.Adapter.map App.Product,
  categories:
    serialized: 'ids'
```

With this in place, when I commit a `Product` the json would contain a key `category_ids` wich contain the array of associated categories ids.

UPDATE:

To properly use the `App.Serializer` defined, you should add it to the adapter of your application :

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  serializer: App.Serializer
```

And to use this adapter in your application, you have to set it in the store :

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: 'App.Adapter'
```

Comment: I've added your serializer code to store.rb and the following to one of my models:

     `FP.Adapter.map FP.observation,
       students:
         serialized: 'ids'`

However when I commit like:

    `obs.get('students').pushObjects(selected)
    obs.get('transaction').commit()`

I don't see any call to your serializer code? It should be called on commit, right?

Comment: Yes it should be called on commit if the record is dirty, is a request properly fired in your case ? If not, you may have to mark the record dirty manually as modifying a *many to many* relationship does not flag the record as dirty.

Comment: The request is fired, I can see it in the network tab. In the json sent to the server the students member of the Observation is an empty array. When I dug down into ember-data I can see it looking through the `relationships` of the Observation model. This only contains the `belongsTo` relationships and none of the `hasMany` relationships. I guess this is why `addHasMany` is not called. So it finds the room and educator data and adds those to the json, but not the student data.

Comment: Are you using the last version of Ember Data ? Actually, I only used this code with last version or at least from Revision 11.

Comment: Yep, I'm using Revision 12. // Last commit: 9859dfc (2013-04-12 12:07:41 -0700) - I've resorted to stepping through ember-data, and can see the relationships being created. Haven't got down to the level  of the serializer yet though.

Comment: Maybe you should remove `embedded: true` as this syntax is not available anymore in Rev 12. I don't think the problem came from here but this code is working properly in my case :s

Comment: I got it working by changing your serializer modification from `App.Serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend` to `DS.RESTSerializer.reopen`. The `addHasMany` is called now and the data is being sent back to the server.

Comment: Oh I understand now, this is because you did not use the `App.Serializer` defined in your application, will update my answer with the config to use the proper serializer.